# Regex extraction for first and last name in R

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have a set of data that looks as such:

```
names_data <- structure(list(name = c('Eric Smith ♕',
                         'Dave Holmes - Realtor',
                         'Erin Speck ≈¶',
                         'Michael Jackson | Denver',
                         'Scott Joseph Taylor',
                         'Jeff D. Hill',
                         '|Ryan Armory|',
                         'Lisa Turrow',
                         'Rory Wilcox Makeup Artist',
                         'annie longer // modelingagency',
                         'Leah Young | HOUSTON, TX',
                         'Harley Barvis Jarvis',
                         'Neil Anderson Photography',
                         'Erica Sparkles Jr.',
                         'Jessica Ann Peterson Jr.)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

While I realize there is no one size fits all solution to this and might need to be heavily customized, I would like to get these strings to look something like this:

```
names_regex <- structure(list(name = c('Eric Smith',
                                  'Dave Holmes',
                                  'Erin Speck',
                                  'Michael Jackson',
                                  'Scott Taylor',
                                  'Jeff Hill',
                                  'Ryan Armory',
                                  'Lisa Turrow',
                                  'Rory Wilcox',
                                  'Annie Longer',
                                  'Leah Young',
                                  'Harley Jarvis',
                                  'Neil Anderson',
                                  'Erica Sparkles',
                                  'Jessica Peterson')), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

And once that's done, we would then split them out by first and last name so the final product looks like such:

```
names_final <- structure(list(first = c("Eric", "Dave", "Erin", "Michael", "Scott", "Jeff", "Ryan", "Lisa", "Rory", "Annie", "Leah", "Harley", "Neil", "Erica", "Jessica"), last = c("Smith", 
"Holmes", "Speck", "Jackson", "Taylor", "Hill", "Armory", "Turrow", "Wilcox", "Longer", "Young", "Jarvis", "Anderson", "Sparkles", "Peterson")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

I've tried:

```
names_all <- names_data %>% mutate(name = str_extract(name, "[\\w\\s.]+\\w"))
```

But that doesn't give me what I need.

Comment: What are the pattern requirements, aka "rules for extraction"? You have only provided the input and expected output, it is not how regexps work. Regex is built according to specific matching rules. So what are they here?

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean? I thought I was pretty clear. I'm trying to get `names_data` to look like `names_regex` (and ultimately like `names_final`). Whatever rules you want to use is not of my concern as long as it looks like the output.

Comment: This is an NLP (natural language processing) type of task where you can only ever hope to achieve mediocre results using a "naive" approach such as regular expressions. Using the regex approach to perform what is essentially named-entity extraction inevitably results in increasing complexity as you attempt to deal with edge cases. The preferred approach would be to use a dedicated NLP framework to perform named-entity extraction. See: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html

Comment: What you ask us to do is practically perform machine learning task (you give input and output, nothing esle, and expect some "system" that will enable this conversion). Sorry, we cannot help without explicit rules. Regex = regular language. What you want is NOT regular.

Comment: Based in your examples, you can remove most symbols and outside delimiter text with `gsub("([^a-zA-Z]| )*([a-zA-Z. ]+[a-zA-Z.]).*","\\2", names)` . However a smarter approach would be need to correctly identify Mr. Rory Artist!!

Comment: Impossible with regex.  Pattern matching cannot discriminate between a surname, a role component like Makeup or any other textual embellishments.  Perhaps have a procedure which identifies problem records for manual attentions, then recombine.

Answer (score -2):

Here is some code that uses the `openNLP` package to perform named-entity detection. The results are far from perfect, but using a bit of creativity you can use the output of various annotation operations to obtain acceptable results.

```r
library(openNLP)
library(openNLPmodels.en)
library(NLP)
library(stringr)
# install.packages('https://datacube.wu.ac.at/src/contrib/openNLPmodels.en_1.5-1.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type = 'source')

names_data <- c('Eric Smith ♕',
                'Dave Holmes - Realtor',
                'Erin Speck ≈¶',
                'Michael Jackson | Denver',
                'Scott Joseph Taylor',
                'Jeff D. Hill',
                '|Ryan Armory|',
                'Lisa Turrow',
                'Rory Wilcox Makeup Artist',
                'annie longer // modelingagency',
                'Leah Young | HOUSTON, TX',
                'Harley Barvis Jarvis',
                'Neil Anderson Photography',
                'Erica Sparkles Jr.',
                'Jessica Ann Peterson Jr.')

# a little pre-processing to clean up input data
names_cleaned <- names_data |> 
  iconv(to = 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', sub = 'byte') |>
  str_to_title() |>
  str_replace_all('\\<\\w+\\>', '') |>
  str_squish()

# do nlp stuff
s <- as.String(names_cleaned)
sa <- Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator()
wa <- Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator()
pa <- Maxent_POS_Tag_Annotator()
ea_person <- Maxent_Entity_Annotator(language = 'en', kind = 'person', probs = TRUE)
ea_location <- Maxent_Entity_Annotator(language = 'en', kind = 'location', probs = TRUE)
ea_organization <- Maxent_Entity_Annotator(language = 'en', kind = 'organization', probs = TRUE)
a2 <- annotate(s, list(sa, wa, pa))

# display detected entities of type "person"
s[ ea_person(s, a2) ] |> str_split('\n') |> unlist() |> print()
```

```
 [1] "Eric Smith"                "Dave Holmes"               "Michael Jackson"           "Scott Joseph Taylor"       "Jeff D. Hill"             
 [6] "Armory"                    "Lisa Turrow"               "Rory Wilcox Makeup Artist" "Annie Longer"              "Modelingagency"           
[11] "Leah Young"                "Tx"                        "Harley Barvis Jarvis"      "Neil Anderson Photography" "Erica Sparkles Jr."       
[16] "Jessica Ann Peterson Jr."
```

```r
# display detected entities of type "location"
s[ ea_location(s, a2) ] |> str_split('\n') |> unlist() |> print()
```

```
[1] "Denver"  "Houston"
```

```r
# display detected entities of type "organization"
s[ ea_organization(s, a2) ] |> str_split('\n') |> unlist() |> print()
```

```
[1] "Harley Barvis Jarvis"      "Neil Anderson Photography" "Erica Sparkles Jr."        "Jessica Ann Peterson Jr."
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for putting in the effort on this, I REALLY appreciate it. Problem is though, it looks like it's still not detecting what I'm looking for? For example, `Jessica Ann Peterson Jr.` should be reduced to `Jessica Peterson` etc...

Comment: You can perform further processing on detected entities to remove honorifics, suffixes, etc (example: `str_replace_all('Jr|Sr', '')`)